# Dynamics 365 FetchXml return different results

Tags: javascript, dynamics-365, fetchxml, appointment

We are using `XMLHttpRequest` to fetch appointments from Dynamics 365 using JavaScript. We link `appointment` to `activityparty` to get all the participants, and we succeeded the retrieve the attribute "appointment_activity_parties".

Few days ago we stopped receiving the attribute "appointment_activity_parties". The fetchXml retrieve the records with all the attributes except the "appointment_activity_parties". We didn't change the code.

We started playing with the code and noticed that some of the browsers in Incognito state are working find and getting the party list. Clearing the cache didn't help. Some browsers started working fine after clearing history and then stopped. Some times the fetchXml worked fine in one browser and didn't work in another one in the same computer and the same user.

The only change in the system that we made was changing to 2FA (2-factor Auth). but the problem happened to users using 2FA and to those who doesn't use 2FA.

Any suggestions? We don't have a clue.

Comment: This is odd, but is this somehow related to record specific issue? I know there are many variables already in play - like mfa, user, browser, environment. Take one record and cross check across the diff combo and put down a matrix. Now it’s hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: We have more than 100 users. It’s happened to most of them. The only problem is with the party list in appointments. We are waiting for Microsoft support answers. Until now we have no clue what cause the different fetch.